# Font size less than 1 in scaled HTML5 canvas

Tags: canvas, font-size

I am building a grid of squares with HTML5 canvas 2D context.  I translate & scale the canvas such that the grid squares are one unit in size, but are 30px, say, untransformed. [Here's an example](http://backspaces.net/temp/scaledgrid.png) 10x10 grid of 30px squares.

This works fine except for one thing: text.

To specify a font for the canvas that fits inside a square, I need to specify a font size less than one.

For example, ".5px sans-serif" should be half the square size (i.e. "15px sans-serif" for 30px untransformed squares).  This fails, at least in Chrome, and the canvas reverts to a larger default.

The only solution I've found is to undo the canvas scaling when I draw text, yuk!

Is there a way to solve this via sub-pixel font specifications?  (Naturally after the transformation, the font will be a sane large font.  The sub-pixel font size is only relative to the canvas transform)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting font size to 0.5px means the font is half pixel untransformed. It's not a scale value but an absolute value.

So specify the font size as unscaled size, scale context, draw text and grid, and then optionally remove the scale.

This demo will show this in action:
**[Scale demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gE7x7/)**

The essential part:

```
ctx.font = '15px sans-serif';
ctx.scale(1/30, 1/30);
ctx.fillText('TEXT', 5, 5);
ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, 30, 30);
```

**[Example demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eX2ve/)**

This example will produce a tiny dot in the upper left corner.

Comment: You might prefer save & ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0) below rather than the scale equivalent.

Comment: @backspaces save/restore are rather expensive performance wise (you would need both as they use a push/pop stack approach and they save/retsore the whole context's settings). setTransform is a good alternative to (re)set the scale, but scale is just a wrapper to set the transformation matrix values just as setTransform do, but you'll need setTransform to reset the scale completely as scale() accumulates. Hope the answer helped!

Comment: Ah, I missed that .. avoiding save/restore pairs are definitely a good idea.

Comment: This answer is secretly doing something else helpful: It's offsetting the text by 5,5: ctx.fillText('TEXT', 5, 5); That offset is important, because fillText uses an odd baseline relative to the transform and the text will render so high above the square that you can't see it. You can change 5,5 offset to 0,0 by changing the baseline: ctx.textBaseline = "top";

Answer (score 2):

After thinking this was going to hard, I realized there is a simple solution using transforms.

Consider that the context is currently transformed in a complex way, and I want to draw text at a given location `(tx,ty)`. The only thing you need to know is the current scale, `(scaleX,scaleY)` (which you would need to know anyways to calculate the fractional font size. Then you can translate (in the transformed coordinate system) and then unscale and draw the text:

```
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(tx, ty);
ctx.scale(1/scaleX, 1/scaleY);
ctx.fillText("Some String", 0, 0);
ctx.restore();
```

If you need to do any math relating to the text size, it can be done in the "unscaled" coordinates.

Answer (score -2):

Frankly sub-pixel font size is pretty meaningless. You might instead want to drop the text altogether, or "greek" it with little straight lines to indicate text lines. Use measureText() at some known standard size to get the appropriate relative lengths for each line, then just draw a straight tiny line to indicate the presence of (unreadable) text.

Comment: Fonts scale with the canvas transform, so a ".5px serif" font would be rendered as a 10px font if the ctx.scale were 20. This is the point of my question .. I want to specify a tiny font in the canvas such that, AFTER SCALING turns into a sensible font.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I've had zero luck trying that myself. Perhaps because kerning is applied at the unscaled size. Instead I've ended up placing scale:1.0 text on maps that zoom in and out, and determine the scaled translation values in JS.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. My data is normalized (0-1) and also has arbitrary transforms, which I apply with context transforms. It seems that I just cannot draw text, since anything < .5 just disappears, and .5 is huge (since it is scaled). Is just a bug in the Canvas spec or something? I'd love to see a solution. Also, my transformations are too complex to easily reproduce in javascript.

Comment: I just gave up and scaled using the identity matrix then restoring my earlier scale.  I.e. ctx.save();ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);<draw text>; ctx.restore()